# Google Apps Script - Using onEdit to run script if cell = 'yes'

Tags: javascript, function, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm having trouble understanding the onEdit() function in Google apps script.

I have a Google sheet that has a Master tab, and 4 individual tabs, and I need it to send an email out if a user selects 'Yes' in the 'send email' column of any of the individual sheets. I have a function that does this perfectly, in the debugger, I'll paste it here: (I'm aware that it can probably be simplified/cut down:)

**Code:**

```
 function triggers() {
 //Hold all values of selected sheet
 var zy = holdingData.values;

 for (var j = 0; j < zy.length; ++j) {
     //Get the UI functions and store them in a variable, used for prompts later in the script
     var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

     if (zy[j][9] === 'Yes') {

         //Pull values for later use
         holdingData.selVals.push([zy[j][0], zy[j][1], zy[j][2], zy[j][3], zy[j][4], zy[j][5], zy[j][7], zy[j][23], zy[j][24], zy[j][25]]);

         //Pull Teacher email from Master column B
         holdingData.teacherEmail.push(holdingData.selVal[j][7]);

         //Assign email based on contents of column X
         if (holdingData.selVals[j][8].toLowerCase() === "miranda") {
             holdingData.counselorEmail.push("FakeEmail1@Madeup.com");
         } //.....Other cases after this, cut for length

         //Assign subject line for specified individual
         holdingData.subject.push("Referral: " + holdingData.selVals[j][0] + " " + holdingData.selVals[j][1]);

         //Store columns C,D, and E in 1 variable string for each student
         holdingData.actionsTaken.push(holdingData.selVals[j][2] + ", " + holdingData.selVals[j][3] + ", " + holdingData.selVals[j][4]);

         //Assign Email message contents for specified individual sheet
         holdingData.message.push("The referral submitted for " + holdingData.selVals[j][0] + " " + holdingData.selVals[j][1] + " has been completed. The following action(s) were taken: " + holdingData.actionsTaken[j] + ", Please email the member of the discipline team who handled the referral if you have any questions or concerns, at: " + holdingData.counselorEmail[j] + ".");

         //Prompt user to confirm they would like to send the emails
         var response = ui.prompt('Are you sure you would like to send emails to the selected staff memebers?', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
         if (response === 'YES') {
             //Send Message to Referring teacher
             MailApp.sendEmail(holdingData.teacherEmailMir[j], holdingData.subjectMir, holdingData.messageMir);

             //Send Message to Counselor assigned to student
             MailApp.sendEmail(holdingData.counselorEmailMir[j], holdingData.subjectMir, holdingData.messageMir);
         } else {return;}
     }
 }
```

}

I cut out some for length, but the core of what I want to do is there. If I wrap the whole thing in an onEdit(), it doesn't work. If I apply OnEdit() as a simple trigger (I believe) it will fire this script *every* time any of the sheets are edited. I've tried a few other things, but no luck. What don't I get? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing happens because you are trying to send an email with a simple `onEdit()` trigger. In the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/) under restrictions it's even given as an example

- They cannot access services that require authorization. For example, **a simple trigger cannot send an email because the Gmail service requires authorization**, but a simple trigger can translate a phrase with the Language service, which is anonymous.

Comment: To build on this, a [Custom Menu](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus) could be made with an option to run your code and send the emails. You could also provide an option to check available emails since there is a limit of how many an account can send in a day.  The added benefit here is that the code runs once for all the sends after they have been set to Yes and reviewed for accuracy.  Assuming you are sending more than one, that is.

Comment: I like the idea of a custom menu, and will definitely add one. I think I also understand the difference between the simple triggers and installable ones. What I still don't get is how I would use the function in practice. Would I just set an onEdit() installable and then pass the 'e' argument to function I want it to apply to?